# Proving Logical equivalence [5-26]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, idempotents

I have to prove a problem statement with logical equivalences but I seem to keep getting stuck. Here is the problem: $$ [(q \to p) \land \lnot p] \to (p \land q) \equiv p \lor q $$
Here is the work I have so far:
$$\equiv \lnot [(\lnot q \lor p) \land \lnot p] \lor (p \land q) $$
$$\equiv [( q \land \lnot p) \lor p] \lor (p \land q) $$
$$\equiv [( p \lor q) \land (p \lor \lnot p)] \lor (p \land q) $$
$$\equiv [( p \lor q) \land T] \lor (p \land q) $$
$$\equiv ( p \lor q) \lor (p \land q) $$

Any hints or pointing out mistakes I made so far would be great

Comment: What you have is fine. Now just use one of the absorption laws.

Comment: I seem to have the same problems when it comes to using the laws, but $ p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p $ can be applied to whole terms and not just singular variables?

Comment: Yes: It’s really $x\lor(x\land y)\equiv x$ for arbitrary propositional expressions $x$ and $y$. But here you’re actually doing it with atomic propositional variables, either via $p\lor(p\land q)\equiv p$ or via $q\lor(p\land q)\equiv q$.